# Samba: prevent accidential, recursive mass deletion of files

Tags: permissions, samba, directory, sharing

I am sharing some folders on Ubuntu 18.04, so they can be accessed read/write from windows clients.

File structure:

```
myshare/
  dir1/
     somefile1.txt
     somefile2.txt
  dir2/
  dir3/
```

The samba client have read/write/create/delete permissions to the files inside `dir1`.

I was hit by an unintended user accident:
A user would hit *delete* on `dir1`, and all files inside `dir1` were deleted.

I have not been able to apply permission settings that could prevent this.
This all seems to come down to how samba clients implement a deletion of a folder structure, they do this by listing the folder content and then executing a file deletion one by one, recursively from the deepest level of the directory tree.

Bottom line: On the server side I have no chance to distinguish between the allowed single file deletion and the unwanted, full, recursive folder deletion.

Am I missing something?

I have thought about two tricks but have not been able to figure out any solution:

1. Can I place a file inside `dir1` that would cause the samba client to abort the batch delete operation? I have had some success with placing a *not deletable file* in `dir1`, but the success seems random.
2. I have noticed that if I make `dir1` the root of the share, the above risk is gone. If the user then presses delete on `dir1` the operation is denied, which is perfect. But having `dir1`, `dir2`, `dir3` etc as separate shares does not scale well. I want the user to have only one access point `/myshare`. But is there a way to make `dir1` behave like a share (so a client can browse it but not delete it) and yet still appear inside `/myshare`?

A solution that works just for windows file explorer clients would be acceptable.

Comment: Is there anything in this post which helps? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91503/345853

Comment: Do you want users to be able to delete files?

Comment: Yes, that is an essential part of the problem: Users should be able to delete files that they specifically request deleted.